# How to set two versions of text colours in raspberry Pi using joystick to switch?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
sense=SenseHat()
 
def black():
    sense.clear(0,0,0)

def white():
    sense.clear(255,255,255)

sense.stick.direction_left=sense.show_message(text_colour=black,back_colour=white,scroll_speed=0.05)

sense.stick.direction_right=sense.show_message(text_colour=white,back_colour=black,scroll_speed=0.05)


while True:
    print ("Hello World")
```

The system shows: `TypeError:show_message() missing 1 required positional argument:text_string`

Wondering what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

`sense.stick.direction_left` and `sense.stick.direction_right` are supposed to be assigned functions that will be called when the joystick is pushed either left or right. Your code actually assigns the *return* value from calling the function `sense.show_message()`, which is always `None`.

Regarding the error message that you see from the exception, you are missing the actual message. `show_message()` requires a *positional* argument which is the string for the message that you want shown. Try this:

```
from signal import pause
from sense_hat import SenseHat

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

def pushed_left(event):
    sense.show_message('Left', text_colour=BLACK, back_colour=WHITE, scroll_speed=0.05)

def pushed_right(event):
    sense.show_message('Right', text_colour=BLACK, back_colour=WHITE, scroll_speed=0.05)

sense = SenseHat()
sense.stick.direction_left = pushed_left
sense.stick.direction_right = pushed_right

pause()
```

Here the functions to call when the joystick is pushed are assigned properly, and the first argument to `show_message()` is supplied. Notice that the function objects are not called, they are merely referenced.

Note also that the colour arguments to `show_message()` should be tuples or lists. Your code assigns a function to these, so it won't work as you might expect. You can create constants with the required values and use these as shown.

Comment: I tried the new code but it won't let me switch through the joystick. Any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: Are you getting the events? Are `pushed_left()` and `pushed_right()` being called? You could add a `print()` to each function to see if they are called.

Comment: Also, see example at the bottom of this page: https://pythonhosted.org/sense-hat/api/. And other examples at https://github.com/RPi-Distro/python-sense-hat/blob/master/examples/README.md

Comment: I figured out that the switching is happening but is occurring after the full text is displayed. Is there any way to make the event happen immediately?